# Gitlab: how to change OS (ssh) user and group for Gitlab installation?

Tags: gitlab

What is the correct way to change default OS (ssh) user and group git/git, which are used during Gitlab installation, to something else (e. g. gitlab/gitlab) ?

After that manipulation a repo address should looks like gitlab@host.com:repo.git, not default git@host.com:repo.git.

It's necessary because default 'git' user is used for another purpose on my server and cannot be used for Gitlab installation.

My OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64

Gitlab installation guide: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps to do:

1. Create a new user (or use another created on) for *GitLab*
2. Change user of **GitLab** in `gitlab.yml` to the new user
3. Change user of **gitlab-shell** in `config.yml` to new user
4. Grant the new user access to **gitlab-shell** and **GitLab** directory
5. Apply all permission instructions from the [installation docs](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) for the new user